# Need help in removing the SOQL query inside FOR loop

Tags: soql, schedulebatch

I have a custom object "Proposal Line Item" which has a lookup to another object "Quote". "Quote" object has a lookup to "Account". This "Account Id" is present in "Proposal Line Item" object as a formula field. Now I need to send email to all the "Account Team Members" of above mentioned account whenever the batch class updates the "Proposal Line Item" record. I have a V.F Email template which is using merge fields of the associated  "Quote" object. I want to remove the SOQL query inside FOR loop whenever I an sending email to "Account Team Members".  Below is my code:

```
 Global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<sObject> scope) 
{
List<Apttus_Config2__PriceListItem__c> UpdatePriceList = (List<Apttus_Config2__PriceListItem__c>)scope;     
Set<ID> PriceListItemIDs = new Set<ID>(); // Set of "Price List Item" Ids
Set<ID> PriceListIDs = new Set<ID>(); // Set of "Price List" Ids
Set<ID> ProductIDs = new Set<ID>(); // Set of "Product" Ids
String x= System.Label.Proposal_LineItem_End_Date; //Retrives custom label value
Integer y = Integer.valueOf(x); //Converts custom label value from string to Integer

for(Apttus_Config2__PriceListItem__c getPriceListrecords : UpdatePriceList) 
  {
    PriceListItemIDs.add(getPriceListrecords.id);  //Adding PriceListItem Id's to the set 
    PriceListIDs.add(getPriceListrecords.Apttus_Config2__PriceListId__c);  //Adding Price List Id's to the set 
    ProductIDs.add(getPriceListrecords.Apttus_Config2__ProductId__c);  //Adding the Product Id's to the set 
  }

    //Query to get all ProposalLineItem Id's whose PriceList/Product Ids are same as in PriceLineItem.
    List<Apttus_Proposal__Proposal_Line_Item__c> proposal = [Select ID,Apttus_Proposal__Proposal__c,APTS_Expired__c,Apttus_QPConfig__EndDate__c ,Publishing_Status__c,AccountId__c from Apttus_Proposal__Proposal_Line_Item__c where Apttus_QPConfig__PriceListId__c In :PriceListIDs AND Apttus_Proposal__Product__c In :ProductIDs]; // Listing Related proposals                                

    //Getting Proposal Line Items that has to be updated.              
    List<Apttus_Proposal__Proposal_Line_Item__c> PrsToUpdate = new List<Apttus_Proposal__Proposal_Line_Item__c>();
    for(Apttus_Proposal__Proposal_Line_Item__c prpsl : proposal) 
    {          
      if (prpsl.APTS_Expired__c==false)//Filtering the records where Expired=false
      {
          prpsl.Apttus_QPConfig__EndDate__c=system.today().adddays(y); 
          prpsl.Publishing_Status__c='To Be Published';
          PrsToUpdate.add(prpsl);
      }
     }
     update PrsToUpdate;          

     List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> emails=new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
     EmailTemplate templateId = [Select id from EmailTemplate where name = 'Update_Expiry_Date'];                 
     for(Apttus_Proposal__Proposal_Line_Item__c Prs1 : PrsToUpdate)
     {            
          List<String> EmailString = new List<String>();
          List<User> Users1 = [Select id,Email from User where Id in(Select UserId from AccountTeamMember where AccountId=:Prs1.AccountId__c)];
          for(User U12 : Users1)
          {
           EmailString.add(U12.Email);
          }

          User AccountOwner = [Select Id from User where ID in(Select OwnerId from Account where Id=:Prs1.AccountId__c)];

          Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email= new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();              
          email.setTargetObjectId(AccountOwner.Id);
          email.setwhatID(Prs1.Apttus_Proposal__Proposal__c);
          email.setSaveAsActivity(false);
          email.setToAddresses(EmailString);
          email.setTemplateID(templateId.Id);
          emails.add(email); 
      }
      Messaging.sendEmail(emails);  }
```

Comment: I have 2 SOQL query inside my last FOR loop. One to get "Account Team Members" and second to get "Account Owner" . I want to remove both queries outside loop.  I have tries 2-3 ways to do it but none of them gives me proper result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some point that I did:

1. When you get the line items, create a set of AccountiDs to query
2. Query AccountTeamMember using relationships to get the data instead of the other queries and store them in a map
3. Use the AccountID__r.OwnerID instead of querying for the Account again

**Important Point**: Use the ability to traverse relationships whenever you can to get all the data you need

There may be other issues that I did not review and it could be refined further but this is a start

I have update your code below:

```
Global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<sObject> scope) 
{
List<Apttus_Config2__PriceListItem__c> UpdatePriceList = (List<Apttus_Config2__PriceListItem__c>)scope;     
Set<ID> PriceListItemIDs = new Set<ID>(); // Set of "Price List Item" Ids
Set<ID> PriceListIDs = new Set<ID>(); // Set of "Price List" Ids
Set<ID> ProductIDs = new Set<ID>(); // Set of "Product" Ids
String x= System.Label.Proposal_LineItem_End_Date; //Retrives custom label value
Integer y = Integer.valueOf(x); //Converts custom label value from string to Integer

for(Apttus_Config2__PriceListItem__c getPriceListrecords : UpdatePriceList) 
  {
    PriceListItemIDs.add(getPriceListrecords.id);  //Adding PriceListItem Id's to the set 
    PriceListIDs.add(getPriceListrecords.Apttus_Config2__PriceListId__c);  //Adding Price List Id's to the set 
    ProductIDs.add(getPriceListrecords.Apttus_Config2__ProductId__c);  //Adding the Product Id's to the set 
  }

    //Query to get all ProposalLineItem Id's whose PriceList/Product Ids are same as in PriceLineItem.
    List<Apttus_Proposal__Proposal_Line_Item__c> proposal = [Select ID,Apttus_Proposal__Proposal__c,APTS_Expired__c,Apttus_QPConfig__EndDate__c ,Publishing_Status__c,AccountId__c from Apttus_Proposal__Proposal_Line_Item__c where Apttus_QPConfig__PriceListId__c In :PriceListIDs AND Apttus_Proposal__Product__c In :ProductIDs]; // Listing Related proposals                                
    //Get account IDs
    Set<ID> acctIDs = New Set<ID>();

    //Getting Proposal Line Items that has to be updated.              
    List<Apttus_Proposal__Proposal_Line_Item__c> PrsToUpdate = new List<Apttus_Proposal__Proposal_Line_Item__c>();
    for(Apttus_Proposal__Proposal_Line_Item__c prpsl : proposal) 
    {          
      if (prpsl.APTS_Expired__c==false)//Filtering the records where Expired=false
      {
          prpsl.Apttus_QPConfig__EndDate__c=system.today().adddays(y); 
          prpsl.Publishing_Status__c='To Be Published';
          PrsToUpdate.add(prpsl);
          acctIDs.add(prpsl.AccountID__c);
      }
     }
     update PrsToUpdate;          

     List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> emails=new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
     EmailTemplate templateId = [Select id from EmailTemplate where name = 'Update_Expiry_Date'];                 
     Map<ID,AccountTeamMember[]> acctTeam = New Map<ID,AccountTeamMember>();
     Map<ID,Account> accts = New Map<ID,Account>([Select Owner.Name From Account Where ID IN :acctIDs]);

     //Get records related to account
     for(AccountTeamMember tm : [Select id, AccountID, user.Email, Account.OwnerID from AccountTeamMember where AccountId in :acctIDs]){
        if(!acctTeam.containsKey(tm.AccountID))
            acctTeam.put(tm.AccountId, New AccountTeamMember[]{});

        acctTeam.get(tm.AccountID).add(tm);
     }


     for(Apttus_Proposal__Proposal_Line_Item__c Prs1 : PrsToUpdate)
     {            
          List<String> EmailString = new List<String>();
          //List<User> Users1 = [Select id,Email from User where Id in(Select UserId from AccountTeamMember where AccountId=:Prs1.AccountId__c)];
          if(acctTeam.containsKey(prs1.AccountID__c)){
              for(AccountTeam U12 : acctTeam.get(prs1.AccountID__c))
              {
               EmailString.add(U12.User.Email);
              }

          }

          //User AccountOwner = [Select Id from User where ID in(Select OwnerId from Account where Id=:Prs1.AccountId__c)];

          Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email= new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();              
          //email.setTargetObjectId(AccountOwner.Id);

          //You will need to handle the possibility that no Account was returned

          if(acts.containsKey(prs1.AccountID__c))
                email.setTargetObjectId(prs1.AccountID__r.OwnerID);

          email.setwhatID(Prs1.Apttus_Proposal__Proposal__c);
          email.setSaveAsActivity(false);
          email.setToAddresses(EmailString);
          email.setTemplateID(templateId.Id);
          emails.add(email); 
      }
      Messaging.sendEmail(emails);  
}
```

Comment: Hello Eric, Thank you for the answer . Everything is working awesome with your provided code except for the part **email.setTargetObjectId(prs1.AccountID__r.OwnerID);**

I get the error saying **Compile Error: Invalid foreign key relationship: Apttus_Proposal__Proposal_Line_Item__c.AccountID__r at line 85 column 35**

Can you please help here too?

Thanks!

Comment: I had tried the same thing before also to get the account owner id but then also it gave me the same error.

Comment: @RuchikaSaxena - What is the API Name of the field on the Proposal Line Item that looks up to the account? Ot is the AccountID__c only a text field storing the Account ID?

Comment: Yes it is Formula (Text) type of field only storing the 15digit account id.

Comment: I have provided my comments above. Can you please help me with this ?

Comment: @RuchikaSaxena - Code updated

Comment: Hello Eric, Thanks for the updated code . But my issue was that I could not use AccountID__r as it is not a lookup field to account. It is a formula field just having the account id. It was not due to blank value in account field. But I have got it fixed by having one more map of (account id, owner id) and fetching its value in the FOR loop by using  **Id AccountOwner = AccOwner.get(prs1.AccountID__c);**    Once again thanks as I was struggling to get the query out of LOOP :-)

Answer (score 1):

Make list of `Users1` & `AccountOwner` outside both loops and use SOQL to store the result their associated SOQL results by mention all ids of `PrsToUpdate` in `in` selector of SOQL quires.

Then use their list of result in loops to get their value & perform operation accordingly.

Please let me know if you understand the logic or need more clarification on it.